# Webdriver and push button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i try to make in webdriver a test.

1. go to http://programyedukacyjne.pl/konkurs/galeria-prac.html
2. click for example first vote "GŁOSUJ [star]" 
   and should appear a box to put email.

But nothing happend just add to url in browser "#vote_box_22"
I tryed use click(), Action and javascript click but still there no appear a form...

here is begine:

```
driver.get("http://programyedukacyjne.pl/konkurs/galeria-prac.html");
    WebElement location = driver.findElement(By.name("filter_miejscowosc"));
    location.sendKeys("nowy sącz", Keys.ENTER);
```

here is where I have problem

```
WebElement voteBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a"));
    voteBtn.click();
```

my secound solution

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(voteBtn).click().perform();
```

Comment: Give a code example of something that you've actually tried

Answer (score 0):

Try using a more specific selector that pinpoints the link more accurately in a less brittle way. The following CSS selector should select the vote link for the first result shown in the list:

```
WebElement voteBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.praca:nth-of-type(1) a[href*='vote_box']"));
voteBtn.click();
```

Comment: It  worsk, but on only main page "http://programyedukacyjne.pl/konkurs/galeria-prac.html". When i search "nowy sacz" and i try to use it, it doesnt work...

Comment: You might need to wait for the page to reload after searching. I used that selector on the search results page & it found the first result so I suspect you're just trying to find it too soon

Comment: What kind of wait should i use?

Comment: There's hundreds of questions & answers on here about how to wait for things, search around and you will find what you're looking for. If you found my answer to  your original question helpful please don't forget to upvote :)